# Permission denied error when trying to delete a file

Tags: vba, permissions

I am admin to my computer.
I am logged into network.
The below procedure runs and crashes 
after line 
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
stating the permission is denied, at `objFile.Delete`.
Why is permission denied?
I am able to delete files and folders from windows explorer.
Why can't the vba program delete it?
Any solutions?
Thanks

```
Sub RecursiveFolderDelete(MyPath As String)

    Dim FileSys As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objSubFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File


    Set FileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = FileSys.GetFolder(MyPath)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, 1) <> "~" And objFile.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:       
     objFile.Delete
        End If
    Next objFile


    Dim Count As Integer
    Count = 0
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Count = Count + 1
        RecursiveFolderDelete MyPath & "\" & objSubFolder.Name
    Next objSubFolder

    On Error GoTo endx:

    If Count = 0 Then
        RmDir MyPath
    Else
        If objFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
            RmDir MyPath
        End If
    End If

endx:
    On Error GoTo 0


    Set FileSys = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objSubFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the file open when you try to delete it?

Comment: No, file is not open.

Comment: Do Kill objFile.Path or FileSys.DeleteFile(objFile.Path) work?